# Changing Firefox properties before installation or with Add-on

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, negotiate

I'm currently writing a documentation about setting up a special Server environment. To use this environment together with firefox it is required to change one property at the about:config window of firefox.

Our customers have big networks and they just can't do that for hundreds of computers in that network. I'm now looking for a solution to easily configure that property `network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris` which has to be completely idiot-proof. This property is related to Kerberos Authentication.

I thought of making a special installation package of firefox which already contains the property or to serve an Add-on or something like that. (Is there an easy way to do that?)

Or is there a more elegant way to setting up firefox to work properly with kerberos?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a preference from an add-on is trivial assuming that you don't have to worry about anyone else setting it; you need the install.rdf of course and then you just need the default preferences file containing your preference.

Actually installing the add-on is probably most easily done by writing an installer that copies the add-on to a separate location (not under the Firefox installation) and then [registers the add-on in the registry](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Adding_Extensions_using_the_Windows_Registry).